# Reading line from console

Tags: c#, windows, console

I'm experiencing problem with reading input from user. Every time it shrinks your input by first character. Like:

input

`test`

what program reads

`est`

I'm using this simple code:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(input + " >> " + psbhc_service.Encrypt(input));
```

Comment: Can you post all your code? (if it is reasonably short)

Comment: what are the statements before your `Console.ReadLine();`?

Comment: tackOverflow also seems to have this problem :(

Comment: @JanSchwar: Are you getting the input from an actual user typing stuff in, or is it redirected from a file or something?

Comment: @MatthewWatson It is directly from console class from MS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you haven't got a `Console.ReadKey()` before the ReadLine().

For example, this will exhibit the behaviour you described:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

If you want to check whether a key is available, use `Console.KeyAvailable`, which doesn't consume the keystroke.